# Prepend folder names to file name

Tags: bash

I'm trying to add the folder name to the names of the files contained in the folders and sub-folders. @nohillside has already provided a command which solves partly this problem; see [Prepend folder names to file name and flatten file structure](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/321543/prepend-folder-names-to-file-name-and-flatten-file-structure/436875#436875).

@nohillside's command does exactly what I'm looking for, but in addition it also moves all the files out of their folders up to the folder from where the command is run. Is there a way to change this command, so that the files remain in their original folders?

#### Before

```
$ tree
.
├── Ts4650_it
│   ├── IMG_3526.jpeg
│   ├── IMG_3527.jpeg
│   ├── IMG_3528.jpeg
│   └── IMG_3529.jpeg
├── Ts5540_fb
│   ├── IMG_2139.jpeg
│   └── Ts5540_fb_2
│       ├── IMG_2141.jpeg
│       └── IMG_2145.jpeg
├── Ts5549_hv
│   └── IMG_3452.jpeg
.
.
```

#### After

```
$ tree
.
├── Ts4650_it
│   ├── Ts4650_it_IMG_3526.jpeg
│   ├── Ts4650_it_IMG_3527.jpeg
│   ├── Ts4650_it_IMG_3528.jpeg
│   └── Ts4650_it_IMG_3529.jpeg
├── Ts5540_fb
│   ├── Ts4650_it_IMG_2139.jpeg
│   └── Ts5540_fb_2
│       ├── Ts5540_fb_2_IMG_2141.jpeg
│       └── Ts5540_fb_2_IMG_2145.jpeg
├── Ts5549_hv
│   └── Ts5549_hv_IMG_3452.jpeg
.
.
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming a simple structure which only is one level deep, running

```
find . -type f -maxdepth 2 \
    -exec sh -c 'for f do df=${f#./}; d=${f%/*}; echo mv "$f" "$d/${df////_}"; done' {} +
```

in the top level folder should work.

If the folder hierarchy is deeper, replace `-maxdepth 2` with whatever is appropriate (or just skip that part).

PS: As written this will just print the `mv` commands without executing them. If they look ok, **remove the `echo` to actually rename the files.**